# Android Studio doesn't recognize Facebook imports

Tags: android, facebook, import, android-studio, sdk

I'm a begginer and I am trying to create an app with Facebook Integration.

I have done all the steps(Importing Facebook SDK in Module Structure,adding missing depedencies in gradle files,adding the dependencies module for my app project in Structure again).
Everything seemed to be fine,I added A simple LoginButton in main_activity.xml) and no error showed up.

Since I tried to do all the facebook imports needed in MainActivity.java, they all turned red. Those were imports like:

```
    import com.facebook.Session;
    import com.facebook.SessionState;
    import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
    import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
    import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback;
```

and messages like "symbol session cannot be resolved". I googled it as much as I could,couldn't find a solution that worked for me.
At the opposite, this didn't seem to have a problem:

```
    import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
```

Here is my Android Manifest File XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.user.moviere" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.user.moviere"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // compile project(':facebook')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
   }
```

Comment: try a build on the command line ( outside AS ) using "--info" switch... ./gradlew clean assemble_______    and see what you get regarding FB imports. or try diff FB version of sdk dependency

Comment: build on command line:
:app:processDebugResources FAILED
:app:processDebugResources (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 1.79 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.facebook'
  You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
  However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0

BUILD FAILED
Total time: 38.199 secs

Comment: ok .. search all the jars , ./lib,  ./libraries  .... find the dupe for the FB dependency. look at your file system in the project . u have duped the FB somehow

Comment: I just can't figure it out how to find the duplicant..Could I provide you with something more in order to help me? Sorry for my silly questions but it's just too new to me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I created the project from the beginning,imported the FB SDK again. But the real problem with the imports was that Facebook SDK 4 has changed some of the functions,one of them is UiLifecycleHelper for example, it doesn't exist anymore.

Full details about all the changes is here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x

Comment: But they still use these classes(Session, SessionState) in their official documentation, which is why I lost 2 hours finding about this until I stumbled upon this question.

Answer (score 2):

yeah in the current update of the facebook sdk they have removed Session , now AccessToken, LoginManager and CallbackManager classes supercede and replace functionality in the Session class.

For more details go to -
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x

Answer (score 2):

**Update Facebook Dependency**

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'

**Need Permission in Manifest File**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
        android:value="@string/app_name" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1854328631556764"
        android:exported="true" />
```

**Its Working**

More Details :-

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x